# No muestra el ultimo textview de la derecha en Android studio

Tags: android-studio, android-layout, linearlayout

Tengo una aplicación en android studio, estoy usando linearlayout y tablelayout, en el diseño de desarrollo es así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero cuando lo ejecuto para verlo en mi celular, la ultima columna, llamada **"ULTIMO"**,no la muestra. ¿A que se deberá?.

El codigo que tengo es el siguiente:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".SolicitudesCotizacionListado">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#1754EC"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="10dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Solicitudes de Cotizaciones"
            android:textSize="22dp" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/btn_salir_sol_cot"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_gravity="right"

            android:layout_weight="1"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_cerrar_sesion_power_24" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView6"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:text=" N°OT " />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView7"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:text=" N°SC " />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView8"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingLeft="30dp"
                android:paddingTop="10dp"
                android:paddingRight="30dp"
                android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                android:text="Fecha" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView9"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:text="SC" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView10"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:text="Conf." />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView11"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:text="Subir" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView13"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="ULTIMO" />
        </TableRow>

    </TableLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tengo el telefono motorola

Captura desde el telefono:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Tal vez no tenga espacio para dibujarlo. Puedes compartir una captura?

Comment: @Mateo, puse una captura del dispositivo que uso, un motorola

Comment: Me refería a una captura de la aplicación en tu dispositivo.

Comment: @Mateo, ahora si

Answer (score 0):

puede que el layout en el que estas diseñando sea de un tamaño de pantalla mayor al de tu dispositivo de pruebas
[image: Revisa esta parte]

Revisa esta configuración y la de tu emulador. Puede que el tamaño del layout sea mayor al que estas emulando

Saludos

Comment: puse una captura del dispositivo. Sigo igual.:/